# Timesheet: Need to exclude times outside of scheduled hours

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to exclude times outside of scheduled hours.  My data is exported from Access.  I'm trying to use an IF formula and keep getting errors.  =IF(J2<7:00:00 AM,7:00:00 AM,J2)  I keep getting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming J2 is a numeric value formatted as a time (e.g. 7/24 = 0.29166... = 7AM), you could convert the string you're using to a time:

```
=IF(J2<TIMEVALUE("7:00:00 AM"),TIMEVALUE("7:00:00 AM"),J2)
```

Or

```
=MAX(J2,TIMEVALUE("7:00:00 AM"))
```

Alternatively, you could type 7:00:00 AM into a cell (it will be interpreted as a time, stored as a number, and displayed in the same format) and compare J2 to it in your formula.

If J2 is actually a string (doubtful if exported from Access) you would have to convert it to a time as well using `=TIMEVALUE(J2)`